# Converting string to bigdecimal in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, bigdecimal

1. How do I convert following String output into BigDecimal?

   ```
   new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format(
     new Double((
       $V{xHrAdm}.doubleValue()*$V{xHrAdm}.doubleValue() +
       $V{xFodaBnB}.doubleValue()*$V{xFodaBnB}.doubleValue() +
       $V{xChem}.doubleValue()*$V{xChem}.doubleValue() +
       $V{xSCMnQA}.doubleValue()*$V{xSCMnQA}.doubleValue() + 
       $V{xPCO}.doubleValue()*$V{xPCO}.doubleValue() +
       $V{xComp.Eng}.doubleValue() * $V{xComp.Eng}.doubleValue()) / 6))
   ```
2. I also want the square root of the above expression

Answer (score 0):

1.) Why do you need to convert it to String first and then to BigDecimal? You could convert it directly to BigDecimal using the [double constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) like this:

```
new BigDecimal(
$V{xHrAdm}.doubleValue()*$V{xHrAdm}.doubleValue() +
$V{xFodaBnB}.doubleValue()*$V{xFodaBnB}.doubleValue() +
$V{xChem}.doubleValue()*$V{xChem}.doubleValue() +
$V{xSCMnQA}.doubleValue()*$V{xSCMnQA}.doubleValue() + 
$V{xPCO}.doubleValue()*$V{xPCO}.doubleValue() +
$V{xComp.Eng}.doubleValue() * $V{xComp.Eng}.doubleValue()) / 6)
```

And then apply the format to the cell.

2.) To get the square root you can use the [sqrt method of the Math class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) like this:

```
new BigDecimal(
Math.sqrt(
$V{xHrAdm}.doubleValue()*$V{xHrAdm}.doubleValue() +
$V{xFodaBnB}.doubleValue()*$V{xFodaBnB}.doubleValue() +
$V{xChem}.doubleValue()*$V{xChem}.doubleValue() +
$V{xSCMnQA}.doubleValue()*$V{xSCMnQA}.doubleValue() + 
$V{xPCO}.doubleValue()*$V{xPCO}.doubleValue() +
$V{xComp.Eng}.doubleValue() * $V{xComp.Eng}.doubleValue()) / 6))
```